# Get each element from array as string actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I have an array like var test:Array = new Array("a", "b", "c"); How can I write a method to get one element and make it be string each time when I call this method. i.e when I call the method, it should return only 'a' and next time return only 'b' and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use function shift of Array,here is a link about the function [array shift](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#shift%28%29)

```
var test:Array = new Array("a", "b", "c"); 
var firstLetter:String = test.shift();//"a"
var secondLetter:String = test.shift();//"b"
var thirdLetter:String = test.shift();//"c"
```

Answer (score 1):

@Pan's answer is correct, but I feel the need to flag the fact that `shift()` ignites an extremely slow process of re-indexing your entire array. It's not something you need to concern yourself with with small arrays like in your example, but for larger arrays there's a significant performance boost if you `reverse()` the array first and then use `pop()`. I'll create a performance comparison below.

Set up our test arrays:

```
var shiftCopy:Array = [];
var popCopy:Array = [];

for(var i:int = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    var rand:Number = Math.random() * i;

    shiftCopy.push('a' + rand);
    popCopy.push('a' + rand);
}
```

Run the tests:

```
// Using shift.
var t:int = getTimer();
while(shiftCopy.length > 0) shiftCopy.shift();
trace(getTimer() - t);


// Using reverse and pop.
t = getTimer();
popCopy.reverse();
while(popCopy.length > 0) popCopy.pop();
trace(getTimer() - t);
```

My results:

```
shift:  1651ms
pop:    19ms
```